# Tuple and List to formatted string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

In Python3.4 I have a tuple

```
t = ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

and a list

```
l = ['P', 'Q', 'R']
```

and I need to convert the tuple to a string formatted as `"(#A;#B;#C)"` and the list to a string formatted as `"(@P; @Q; @R)"`. The obvious way is to traverse using a for loop and string manipulation.

Is there a way to do it without running the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really insist on your format and no for loops, then probably try something like the following:

```
l_result = '(@' + '; @'.join(l) + ')'
t_result = '(#' + ';#'.join(t) + ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a loop? This can be done very simply using a comprehension:

```
>>> t = ('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> '({})'.format(';'.join('#{}'.format(s) for s in t))
'(#A;#B;#C)'
>>> 
>>> l = ['P', 'Q', 'R']
>>> '({})'.format('; '.join('@{}'.format(s) for s in l))
'(@P; @Q; @R)'
>>>
```

Comment: Not backwards... It's the same order. You just have a 2nd format outside... damn.

Comment: Lol. Don't be to hard on your-self ;)

Answer (score 0):

If not using a loop is the case, another approach can be to convert them to string and use replace method of string, as follows

```
str(t).replace("', '", ";#").replace("('", "(#").replace("')", ")")


str(l).replace("', '", '; @').replace("['", "(@").replace("']", ")")
```

If there are only three elements, you can replace them individually as well.

Answer (score 0):

No explicit loops, not even as list comprehension:

```
>>> t = ('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> l = ['P', 'Q', 'R']
>>> '(' + (len(t) * '#%s;')[:-1] % t + ')'
'(#A;#B;#C)'
>>> '(' + (len(l) * '@%s; ')[:-2] % tuple(l) + ')'
'(@P; @Q; @R)'
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know why you dont want to use the for loop, but you can do it using list comprehension, you will use the for loop, but in a prettier way

```
l = ['P', 'Q', 'R']

new = '('+'; '.join(['@'+i for i in l])+')'

print(new)
(@P; @Q; @R)
```

you could do the same for the tuple.

Comment: Your method will not give the other brackets.

Comment: i know, it can be easily added, i was showing the 'method' of doing the task with a nicer 'for' loop.